# Can't submit app with in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I try to submit app with in-app purchases but apple-people reject it.

> Thank you for submitting the new binary.
>
> However, we still found that while you have submitted In App Purchase
>   products for your app, the In App Purchase functionality is not
>   present in your binary. Please see the attached screenshot/s for more
>   information.
>
> If you would like to utilize In App Purchase in your app, you will
>   need to upload a new binary that incorporates the In App Purchase API
>   to enable users to make a purchase.
>
> Once you revise and resubmit your binary, you will also need to
>   resubmit your In App Purchases for review since they are in the state
>   Developer Action Required. For each IAP product submitted, please be
>   sure to edit the detail information or cancel the request to change
>   the detail information for the In App Purchases using iTunes Connect.
>
> For more information on how to implement In App Purchase in your
>   application, please refer to the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.
>
> You can learn more about submitting In App Purchases for review in the
>   In-App Purchase Configuration Guide for iTunes Connect.

They show the screenshot without products.

[image]

But we tested on test user account and no errors found.

[image]

Can anybody know why in-app products not presented on screenshots of reviewers?
And what is the "Developer Action Needed"?

Comment: After apple rejects an in app purchase, you see that message "Developer Action Needed". You need to update your in app purchase description with a single space and save the description (you can even edit it again afterwards and remove the space). This will get rid of that message.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: Don't be so naive fella. Hide personal information from you screenshots by simple blurring it. Good luck.

Comment: This question not about code, right. But without the submission all code is the waste of time. I don't understand why they reject app with the binary with StoreKit.framework and working code (tested purchases). Do I need to do some other actions: wait until they accept products and only after that submit app for review, or may be to do some other manipulations in itunesconnect before submit app for review?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Apple's In App Purchases API? Because they seem to say that you don't. Most probably they run some automatic tests which detects if such functionality/framework is present/used or not. If you do and it seems confusing, you better contact them.

Comment: I use StoreKit.framework and on test version no errors

Comment: And did you know about In-App Purchase section. Why the status developer action needed? In resolution center no one answer the question.